# Can a Profile have hidden fields with preselescted or predefined values?

Tags: civimember, profile

I'm trying to create a profile to be used as a form, but rather than having the user populate certain fields, have the form populate them automatically. An example of what I'm trying to do:

The profile form is only presented to people that are registering as guests, therefore I want to pre-select the Membership Type as `Guest` rather than allowing the user to select the membership type. In fact, I don't even want the user to see the membership type field.

I'm running CiviCRM 4.7.6 on WordPress 4.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a custom template page with jquery to do something similar. (I wanted the event to assume they were registering themselves and one other person - and NOT allow them to see they could choose how many.)

I wrote a quick jquery statement to preselect the value and then hide the option altogether with css.

https://civicrm.org/blog/hershel/how-customize-civicrm-pages-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use CiviCRM hooks as Hook functions  allow module-extensions to run extra logic as part of the normal CiviCRM processing

A video could be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbaGAy2EJIs) , In this video, an extension i created and it is demonstrated how to preset custom fields with values when the form load s

You can as well look at [Implementing hooks within an extension](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CiviRules. It could potentially add a Guest Membership based on people who fill in that profile being added to a specific group, so base the rule off 'if contact is added to Group x, then give them membership type Y".

Above suggestion is just that, i have not gone in to CiviRules to verify